# Not able to select multiple gridview items

Tags: java, android, gridview, image-gallery, multiple-select

I have an image gallery app . I can select only a single image at a time right now. But I want to be able to select multiple images and deleting them at a time. I tried some code  based on this problem [How to do multiselect functionality on grid view items on tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633672/how-to-do-multiselect-functionality-on-grid-view-items-on-tap) but I am not sure why it is not working. Any suggestions?

**PhotosActivity.java**

```
public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int int_position;
    private GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mSelected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean boolean_folder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, al_images, int_position);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String abc = "file://" + al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                i.putExtra("folderPosition", int_position);
                i.putExtra("abc", abc);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                Integer position1 = new Integer(position);
                if(mSelected.contains(position1)) {
                    mSelected.remove(position1); // remove item from list
                    // update view (v) state here
                    // eg: remove highlight
                }
                else {
                    mSelected.add(position1); // add item to list
                    // update view (v) state here
                    // eg: add highlight
                }
}
```

Comment: You May Follow this link. Hope this will help [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633672/how-to-do-multiselect-functionality-on-grid-view-items-on-tap)

Comment: Instead of removing the selected items on the click, try adding the positions into a different arrayList and when user clicks the done button, then delete the selected images by iterating the positions array.

Comment: I am following that link only, I took the code from there only but somehow its not working for me @bluedream

Comment: @SonuSanjeev I am trying to add positions into _mSelected_ which is the different arraylist but still I am able to select one item at a time only

Comment: what exactly not working ? are you able to update your list of selected items ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take a field selected in the model class. whenever an item is
   selected set selected=true and notifyAdapter .
2. in your onBindViewHolder() of adapter if item isSelected change
   background of the view (dont forget to write the else block ).
3. Also to delete the items maintain a separate list of the objects in the adapter or activity.

In Your Code : I would suggest rather than maintaining positions maintain list of objects . 
Use the above 2 steps to make change in the view of items when selected .
hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be the way could follow as below

- Maintain a list which will contain the positions of currently
  selected items.
- You have to update the view, to show if item is   selected or not, I
  will add code (+comments) on where to do that.
- In the end, the list will contain all items which have been selected.

Something like that [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633672/how-to-do-multiselect-functionality-on-grid-view-items-on-tap)